# Convert points to line segment

Tags: qgis, well-known-text, mysql, points-to-line, segment

In MySQL, I have two tables to store GPS trackpoint and second table to store chainage values. Lines can have more than one condition.
I wish to generate line segments by using both tables above. 
Please see the attached images for both tables:

Table:**Trackpoint**

```
r_id    chainage    latitude    longitude
5246    0   12.251324   105.984187
5246    5   12.251354   105.984224
5246    6   12.251357   105.984219
5246    8   12.25137    105.984231
5246    9   12.251374   105.984222
5246    9   12.251374   105.984217
5246    9   12.251374   105.984217
5246    10  12.251373   105.984217
5246    17  12.251307   105.984206
5246    38  12.251117   105.984186
5246    42  12.251082   105.984184
5246    60  12.250926   105.984155
5246    88  12.250668   105.98414
5246    125 12.250338   105.984167
5246    129 12.250311   105.984186
5246    133 12.250278   105.984209
5246    138 12.250246   105.984233
5246    189 12.249824   105.984432
5246    275 12.249232   105.984933
5246    389 12.248444   105.985601
5246    475 12.247789   105.986025
5246    493 12.247635   105.986089
5246    503 12.247557   105.986123
5246    622 12.246541   105.986484
```

and

Table: **Chainage**

```
R_ID    Start_Chainage  End_Chainage    Condition
5246    0               10              Good
5246    10              50              Bad
5246    50              100             Fair
5246    100             140             Good
5246    140             230             Bad
5246    230             500             Poor
5246    500             627             Good
```

How do I generate a view, which able to draw a line in QGIS. similar this [image: road_line_condition.]

I have tried this: , but the result is not as expected.

```
SELECT
  `t1`.`id`             AS `id`,
  `t1`.`chainage`       AS `chainage`,
  `t2`.`start_chainage` AS `start_chainage`,
  `t2`.`end_chainage`   AS `end_chainage`, 
  `t2`.`condition`    AS `Condition`,
   ST_GeomFromText(CONCAT("LineString(", GROUP_CONCAT(T1.longitude,' ',T1.latitude SEPARATOR ','), ")", ""),4326) AS line_wkt

FROM (`trackpoint` `t1`
   LEFT JOIN `Chainage` `t2`
     ON (`t1`.`r_id` = `t2`.`R_id`))
WHERE t1.`chainage`>=t2.`start_chainage` AND t1.`chainage`<=t2.`end_chainage`
GROUP BY t2.`end_chainage`
```

Comment: Please mark question as answered if it helped you to solve your problem, or put a comment for further elaboration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First I don't see ID column in your sample data. If you don't have it I'd suggest to add it. You can check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7491634/adding-a-primary-key-to-a-mysql-table-and-auto-populating-it) out to find more information.

If you have ID then you can join point to a previous point. Here is an example SQL. I checked it and it works.

```
SELECT t1.r_id, t1.id, t1.chainage AS t1_chainage, t2.r_id, t2.id, t2.chainage AS 
t2_chainage, c1.condition AS c1_condition, c2.condition AS c2_condition,
    ST_GeomFromText(CONCAT("LineString(", t1.lat,' ',t1.lon,',',t2.lat,' ',t2.lon, ")", ""),4326) AS line_wkt
FROM trackpoint t1
JOIN trackpoint t2 ON t2.id = t1.id-1
JOIN chainage c1 ON c1.r_id = t1.r_id AND t1.chainage >= c1.start_chainage AND t1.chainage < c1.end_chainage
JOIN chainage c2 ON c2.r_id = t2.r_id AND t2.chainage >= c2.start_chainage AND t2.chainage < c2.end_chainage
WHERE t1.id > 1;
```

In this select you join point to a previous point. ID of a first point must be greater then 1 (hence where clause).
You have lines that fall into different condition classes. That's why you have in the list of columns c1_condtion and c2_condition. Based on your needs you can use first, second or both.

In addition to your comment from May 8th, 2020 below is a query which returns linestring grouped by condition (condition at end point).

```
SELECT c2.condition, ST_AsText(
  ST_GeomFromText(CONCAT(
    'LineString (',
    GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(t2.lat,' ',t2.lon) SEPARATOR ','),
    ')'
  ),4326)
)
FROM trackpoint t1
JOIN trackpoint t2 ON t2.id = t1.id-1
JOIN chainage c1 ON c1.r_id = t1.r_id AND t1.chainage >= c1.start_chainage AND t1.chainage < c1.end_chainage
JOIN chainage c2 ON c2.r_id = t2.r_id AND t2.chainage >= c2.start_chainage AND t2.chainage < c2.end_chainage
GROUP BY c2.condition;
```

Comment: I followed your query, but it does not work. I want to draw lines by group by chainage.

Comment: It is not returning what you need or it is not correct? The query I gave returns a list of line segments with related conditions. You used GROUP BY expression in your query, but you cannot use it like that. You need to put in a select attributes what you use in GROUP BY part and additionally aggregate function.

Comment: The query result is too many records for one road. I have more than 10000 roads, so it will be problem for the performance between database and GIS application. Any way to GROUP BY the same chainage?

Comment: I've added a new query which uses group by expression. You can change attributes which you like to use in group by expression.

Comment: thanks your trying to help. For your last query, each section is not connect to each other.